# Python / TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Jugador object

Tags: python

Hey guys im trying to create N objects inside a for loop, but it gives me an error `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Jugador object`.

can u help me pls?

what im doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
from Jugador import Jugador
class Juego():
    tipoJuego = ""
    nJugadores = ""


    def __init__(self,tipoJuego, nJugadores):
        self.tipoJuego = tipoJuego
        self.nJugadores = nJugadores
        nJugadoresInt = int(nJugadores)
        tipoJuegoInt = int(tipoJuego)


        if tipoJuegoInt == 1 or tipoJuegoInt == 2 or tipoJuegoInt == 3:
            print("Has elegido el tipo de juego ",tipoJuegoInt, ", y van a jugar ", nJugadores, " Personas")
        else:
            print("Error: Tipo de juego invalido")
            exit()


        for i in range(1,nJugadoresInt):
            print("Jugador",i, "introduzca el nombre de usuario:")
            nUsu = input()

            print("Introduzca la edad:")
            age = input()

            print("Introduzca la palabra elegida:")
            word = input()

            J,i = Jugador(nUsu, age, word)
```

Comment: You are trying to unpack a Jugador instance to `J, i`, which is not defined. Why do you think this is possible? What type is Jugador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to create a way to assign the N objects to find them back later, I can propose to store them in a list `J` :

```
from Jugador import Jugador
class Juego():
    tipoJuego = ""
    nJugadores = ""


    def __init__(self,tipoJuego, nJugadores):
        self.tipoJuego = tipoJuego
        self.nJugadores = nJugadores
        nJugadoresInt = int(nJugadores)
        tipoJuegoInt = int(tipoJuego)


        if tipoJuegoInt == 1 or tipoJuegoInt == 2 or tipoJuegoInt == 3:
            print("Has elegido el tipo de juego ",tipoJuegoInt, ", y van a jugar ", nJugadores, " Personas")
        else:
            print("Error: Tipo de juego invalido")
            exit()

        J = []
        for i in range(1,nJugadoresInt):
            print("Jugador",i, "introduzca el nombre de usuario:")
            nUsu = input()

            print("Introduzca la edad:")
            age = input()

            print("Introduzca la palabra elegida:")
            word = input()

            J.insert(i,Jugador(nUsu, age, word))
```

For reference : https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html